# Using URLStream to load part of a file

Tags: actionscript-3

When loading a file using a URLStream (or a URLLoader) is there any way to specify a range of bytes to load instead of loading the entire file in to memory?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a broad question because of nuances.  The short answer is **No, loading URLs will give you the complete resource**.

The longer answer:

[URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) - No; it loads the complete resource.  You do get `progress` events which tell you how much of the file has been loaded.

[URLStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) - Maybe; it makes data available in chunks as it is loaded.  You can close the stream before it finishes downloading if the data you care about is at the beginning of the file.  Note that the data is in raw binary form.

Revisit `URLLoader` - Maybe; you could write a server that takes a `beginIndex` and an `endIndex`, then call `URLLoader.load('http://my-server/file?beginIndex=' + desiredBeginIndex + '&endIndex=' + desiredEndIndex);`

You'll end up with only the portion of the file that you care about if you have a way of knowing which indices to specify.

Comment: ? You could get the bytesLoaded from the URLLoader and write those avail bytes from data to a byte array from a progress event couldn't you?

Comment: @quantomworks Not with URLLoader.  Its Progress events only give you the # of bytes, not access to the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

...mmm... You could load and track the number of bytes. Then, when you've reached your desired number of bytes loaded, do a `loader.close()`... (Tracking and saving them with a progress event, a byte array, and a global number var)

I dont know about getting data from the middle though, but you can load any range of bytes from the beginning using that method.

[Loader.close()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#close())

> Closes the load operation in progress. Any load operation in progress is immediately terminated. If no URL is currently being streamed, an invalid stream error is thrown.

Comment: Interesting thought.  I'm not sure that the data will be available, though; the docs imply that it's only populated after the COMPLETE event.